# C# to connect to a Progress Database

Tags: c#, openedge, progress-db

I'm trying to develop a program that will connect to a Progress Database (9.1E) using C# (Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate), but I first need to get a connection string to the Progress Database from the C# program.

I have tried the following, but I'm unsuccessful in establishing a connection to the Progress database.  I'm not sure what the connection string should look like, but here's what I have before I start expanding everything.  Also, I'm not sure what the DSN name should be.

```
private void downloadData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string connectString = "DSN = QADDB; Host = ipaddress; DB = dbname; UID = user; PWD = password;";
        IDbConnection dbConn = new OdbcConnection(connectString);
        dbConn.Open();
        IDbCommand dbCommand = dbConn.CreateCommand();
        string sqlstr = "SELECT pt_part FROM pt_mstr";
        dbCommand.CommandText = sqlstr;
        IDataReader reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string part = (string)reader["pt_part"];
            gridview.Items.Add(part);
        }
        reader.Close();
        reader = null;
        dbCommand.Dispose();
        dbCommand = null;
        dbConn.Close();
        dbConn = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

The error message says:

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0X80131937): ERROR [IM002]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified

Comment: please look at [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/progress/)

Comment: This article might be worth looking http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P132748

Comment: You need the port like Ricardo says. Keep in mind that 9.1E is ancient and the SQL support is not that great. Easy to do some simple things but don't be amazed if things don't work like you expect and it is slow.

Comment: Bit late for OP now but always worth checking the ODBC driver is actually installed.

Answer (score 2):

```
string connectString = "DSN=QADDB;uid=username;pwd=password;host=hostname;port=port#;db=dbname;";
using (OdbcConnection dbConn = new OdbcConnection(connectString));
{
    try
    {
        dbConn.Open();
    } catch (Exception)
    {
        mRtnVar = "Couldn't Connect";
        return mRtnVar
    }   
    string sqlstr = string.Format(@"SELECT ""FieldName"" FROM PUB.DataBase WHERE ""FieldName"" = 'value'");
    using (OdbcCommand comm = new OdbcCommand(sqlstr, dbConn))
    {
        using (OdbcDataReader reader = dbConn.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                mRtnVar = reader["FieldName"].ToString();
            }
        }
    } 
    return mRtnVar
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your connection string, set the port of your Progress database:

PORT=20931;

Comment: In case anybody is wondering there is no default port for Progress database (http://www.progresstalk.com/threads/default-port-number-for-progress-database.118006/) which is why you have to specify it in the connection string or DSN.