# Connect to a progress openedge database from C#

Tags: c#, sql, openedge, progress-db

Is it possible to connect to a Progress openedge database in C# and ask it progress questions?
In threads like:
[C# to connect to a Progress Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870818/c-sharp-to-connect-to-a-progress-database)

You show how its done, but you only reach the slow SQL engine. Isnt it possible to reach real progress engine? Today our company use a webservice to reach Progress openedge data.

/Staffan

Comment: Perhaps look into the Open Client? I don't know it will help performance though. https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvnet/using-the-open-client-.net-openapi-to-directly-a.html About performance it could be that your database isn't tuned to your queries. Perhaps have a DBA look into indexing for instance?

Comment: Now I've been checking around a little bit with people in the business, and it looks like this cannot be done. This is probably one of the reasons progress is declining. Its not really open like Sql. Im not sure I use the right term with open here, but this is what it looks like to me.

Comment: You can publish an API from your Progress system at query it instead, you can use SQL (and have somebody look over the performance).